# Parallels: Trying to boot from SATA drive 1

Tags: virtual-machines, windows-10

I'm trying to transfer my windows machine to a virtual machine on my mac. I've tried using Parallels to do so but after trying a few times the data transfer works fine, but the VM always fails to boot into windows 10.

I tried the solution on thier website here  : https://kb.parallels.com/en/113342 but that did not work. I've also tried data transfer via external drive and via network, still did not work.

Has anyone had this issue before?

Answer (score 1):

if anyone runs into a similar problem, I was able to resolve this issue using these steps:

1) Shut down the virtual machine using Actions > Stop menu.

2) Press cogwheel button near the virtual machine's name to open its 
configuration or right-click on virtual machine's name > Configure...

3)Switch to 'Hardware' tab and then select Boot Order from the list of devices.

4) Expand Advanced settings drop-down menu and paste the following system flag:- `vm.bios.efi=1`

5) Start the virtual machine.

Comment: How do you open the configuration as it wants me to book the virtual machine , then i get the windows 7 helper tool. But at that time it wants me to shutdown the virtual machine and the helper tool closes